# Problemas con mi base base de datos?

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp

1.Estoy teniendo problemas al cargar mis datos de mi base de datos con xampp mi proyecto ya esta terminado el problema que no me carga ningun dato de la base de datos solo se me loguea nada mas pero las demas tablas no me funcionan he tratado de buscar informacion pero no encuentro algo que me resuelva el problema
[image: Aqui inicio el proyecto con xampp y no me carga la base de datos]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.solo me funciona si coloco en el simbolo del sistema el comando php artisan serve ahi si me carga todos los datos para que mi proyecto me funcione correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.Cuando ejecuto la sentencia php artisan serve si me funciona correctamente mi base de datos del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**quisiera saber a que se debe este problema para cargar mi base de datos desde xampp y no estar ingresando a cada rato al cmd para estar colocando php artisan serve**

aqui el error que me tira cuando intento ingresar un dato y esta iniciado con xampp y no ingreso con php artisan serve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estuve revisando y haciendo pruebas y me doy cuenta que el problema es con el servidor de apache por que al encender la base si me funciona pero cuando el apache de mi xampp esta apagado y el php artisan serve en mi consola esta ingresado si me corre todo normal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando intento ingresar un registro solo con el servidor de xampp apache sin necesidad de utilizar el php artisan serve en mi cmd
este es el error que me tira lo estaba realizando como prueba para ver si se puede ver mejor el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has intentado reinstalar o reparar la instalacion?

Comment: Agrega la configuración de apache (VirtualHost si es el caso).

Comment: No he intentado reinstalar el xampp por que no se si ese seria el problema en si pero lo intentare a ver si me funciona

Comment: Intente reinstalar el xampp pero sigue con el mismo problema ingrese ala consola y me tira un error ahi dejo la imagen de lo que me tira cuando intento ingresar un registro como que no encuentra la base o las tablas

Comment: lo mas probable es que el problema sea con el usuario de la base de datos. Cual es el usuario de mysql con el que te estas logeando desde la app? verifica que este usuario tenga permisos de lectura a la base de datos, si no los tiene otorgalos con GRANT desde SQL.

Comment: Primero me estoy confundiendo, `php artisan serve` ¿Lo estas usando? ¿Las capturas de la web son usando ese comando? ¿Si usas HeidiSQL (o el que gustes) e intentas conectarte a la base de datos, se conecta correctamente (CON XAMPP LEVANTADO)? ¿Tienes más proyectos de laravel? En caso de sí, ¿Esos otros proyectos funcionan correctamente? ¿Cómo estabas antes? Porque un poco complicado programar un login y mostrar información desde una base de datos programando a ciegas (Digo yo...)

Comment: Estaba utilizando el xampp normalmente y me funcionaba luego intente utilizar el servidor local con php artisan serve pero desde que lo utilice solo asi me encuentra la base de datos de otra forma no

Comment: lo que no entiendo es por que con el php artisan serve ingresado en la consola si me funciona correctamente mi base de datos pero si enciendo mi base de datos desde el xampp no me funciona

Comment: En tu env, cómo tienes el `DB_HOST`?

Comment: estaba revisando y haciendo pruebas y miro que el error es el apache y no la base de datos en si es el servidor ahi dejo una imagen y ver si hay una soluciion para que me funcione solo usando xampp sin necesidad de usar el servidor local con php artisan serve

Comment: Me parece un bug MUY randoongo que el login tira de BD)m. No entiendo porqué usando XAMPP el login funciona (sup, pero el resto de datos no puede acceder/mostrar. Sí usas `artisan serve` funciona perfectamente. Luego, que antes sí funcionaba pero desde que usaste `artisan serve` ya dejó de funcionar con XAMPP. He configurado un Xampp para laravel, ingresando datos y mostrando y todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Creo que solo lo podrías solucionar tú mismo debuggeando con prueba y error, `DB_HOST` de ir con `127.0.0.1` y también ten presente también los comandos `php artisan config:clear` y `php artisan cache:clear`.

Answer (score 2):

Si bien la documentación de Laravel, dice que puedes usar ***Apache*** o ***Nginx*** para levantar las aplicaciones de Laravel, pero si tienes una versión de PHP 5.4 o superior (Que estoy casi seguro que sí), puedes usar el **servidor integrado de PHP**, que en este caso es el ***Serve*** del comando ***Artisan***:

*php artisan serve*

Ahora si no deseas utilizar este comando, y solo usar el *Apache* o *Nginx*, como regularmente hacemos en pruebas de solo ir al htdocs/miapp/index.php y que carguen los datos, lo puedes hacer:

- **Corregir la ruta del htaccess**

  - En el directorio raíz esta el archivo **'server.php'** renombre el archivo a "index.php".
  - Copie ".htaccess" del directorio público al directorio raíz.
  - Ingrese a su proyecto localhost/myproyecto.
  - Y listo está es la manera más sencilla de hacerlo.
  - *En caso de hacerlo de esta manera tenga en cuanta que tendrá que enrutar la carpeta asset y estilo además de que puede provocar algún error cuando ejecuta algún comando artisan, así mismo si esta trabajando con un equipo de desarrolladores sus configuraciones pueden afectar al resto del equipo.*
- ***Hosts virtuales***

Puedes utilizar los host virtuales y configurar tu Apache en tu desarrollo, de manera local.

1. Agrega un host ***(C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)***.
2. Ir a la sig ruta ***(C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf)*** y descomentar las siguientes lineas, (si ya estan descomentadas dejelas así).

   ```
   //# Virtual hosts
   Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf (Descomentar está)
   //Asegurese de tener tambien desmarcada la sig linea
   LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so (Descomentar esta)
   ```
3. Configure el host vaya a la siguiente ruta

**(C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf)**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80> 
       DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/your-project/path-app
       ServerName miapp.dev
    </VirtualHost>
```

4. Despues en el archivo hosts, agregue un nombre para acceder a la dirección

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**

```
#127.0.0.1       localhost 
 127.0.0.1       miapp.dev        #Your host name DNS!
```

5. visitar http:/ /miapp.dev

Y listo debería de funcionar

- De igual forma si a seguido estos pasos puede trabajar con el comando artisan solo comentando el virtual host agregado antes en el archivo ***C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf***

Consulte los siguientes enlaces para saber acerca del Virtual Host, y de las configuraciones del .htacces;

[Usar Laravel sin artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788285/how-to-run-laravel-without-artisan)

[Apache virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

[Creacion de un virtual host sencillo](https://styde.net/creando-virtual-hosts-con-apache-en-windows-para-wamp-o-xampp/)

[Laravel artisan serve](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick)

Comment: ingrese lo primero de usar laravel sin artisan y me sigue con el mismo problema ahi intente realizar un registro solo usando el xampp normal y me tira un error 404 ahi deje una imagen del error que me tira no se si es problema de algun puerto que no me encuentra el apache ya que cuando enciendo el serve de php artisan serve es 8000 pero con el apache es 80

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usas xampp creas proyectos y bases de datos de forma local en la ruta de xampp que suele ser c:/xampp y a estas bases de datos solo podrás acceder de la forma en la que intentas con el mismo servidor xampp.
tu base de datos la has creado con el servidor de php de laravel **php artisan serve** por eso no podrás acceder a esta base de datos usando xampp, para usar esta base de datos desde xampp deberás primero crearla e importar los datos de tu base de datos a este servidor.

Comment: lo intente y me sigue con el mismo problema el apache del servidor xampp no me funciona y es tedioso estar encendiendo el mysql y el servidor de php con php artisan server

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado que no reconoce el **host** `localhost` y lo tengo que cambiar por `127.0.0.1` o viceversa en el archivo `.env`:

```
DB_HOST=localhost // Cambialo por 127.0.0.1 o viceversa
```

Es algo simple, algo que también puedes revisar es que el puerto:

```
DB_PORT=3306 // Revisa que sea el correcto
```

Recuerda limpiar la cache de laravel con `php artisan cache:clear` o reinicia tu servidor, para que lea correctamente tu configuración del archivo `.env`

Saludos!